# Segurança em php falhando

Tags: php, sql

Eu criei um pequeno código de segurança para meu sistema de login, para evitar que pessoas compiem o link do painel administrativo e colassem e conseguissem acessar o mesmo.

```
    <?php
ob_start();
if(($_SESSION['usuarioNome'] == "") || $_SESSION['usuarioNivelAcesso'] == ""){
    $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Área restrita para usuários cadastrados";
    header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Esse trecho acima é o que vê se a pessoa copiou o link ou acessou normal. Porém eu copio e colo o link e acesso normalmente a página administrativa.

Alguma solução?

Comment: Se você copia e cola no mesmo navegador, com os mesmos cookies, você terá acesso. Segundo que é melhor usar `!isset(...)` do que `== ""`, evita erros de "Undefined variable". Se você permitir que a sessão seja passada por parametro de URL você pode copiar o identificador da sessão presente no URL, desligue isso usando `session.use_trans_sid` para `0` e o `session.use_only_cookies` para  `1`.

Comment: Pedro, tem um detalhe que queria saber antes de tirar sua dúvida: quando você diz que copia e cola o link e consegue acessar, você está fazendo isso em outro navegador? Caso esteja fazendo em um mesmo navegador, é normal a sessão permanecer ativa. Tenta acessar copiando e colando o link por outra página.

Comment: Coloca esse código antes do seu `IF` para ver o porque seu código está dando errado: `var_dump($_SESSION['usuarioNome'], $_SESSION['usuarioNivelAcesso'])`

Comment: Fabiano, estou fazendo no mesmo navegador, vou fazer o que você falou agora

Comment: Fabiano, deu isso aqui no var_dump:   C:\wamp64\www\painel_prefeitura\seguranca.php:3:string 'Pedro Henrique Fonseca Ribeiro' (length=30)
C:\wamp64\www\painel_prefeitura\seguranca.php:3:string '1' (length=1)

Comment: @PedroRibeiro isso então responde a tua pergunta, afinal, como podes verificar no var_dump(), as variáveis não estão vazias como você esperava.

Answer (score 6):

Esse código não vai funcionar se você já tiver logado e preenchido esses valores na sessão. A sessão existe no servidor, independente do que você faz no navegador, e só morre após certo tempo sem atividade do usuário ou quando é limpa explicitamente.

Se você quer que a pessoa não consiga acessar colando um link, você precisa fazer a seguinte sequência de passos:

- Gere um valor de sessão (com nome diferente das que guardam nome de usuário e nível de acesso, no seu caso) em qualquer outra página. Indique pelo nome que ela é um token de acesso ou algo do tipo;
- Na página do admin, veja se esse valor na sessão específico está preenchido. Se estiver, permita o acesso, senão, redirecione para outra página;
- Finalmente, ainda na página do admin, **após a verificação acima**, apague o valor. Isso faz com que o próximo acesso à página de admin seja redirecionado. Agora você só poderá acessar a página de admin após acessar a página geradora de token novamente.

**Edição para adicionar código**

Em uma página qualquer, que não seja a do painel, adicione a seguinte lógica:

```
$_SESSION['autorizacaoPainel'] = true;
```

Na página do painel, adicione a seguinte lógica:

```
if ($_SESSION['autorizacaoPainel']) {
    unset($_SESSION['autorizacaoPainel']);
} else {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Assim, você sempre precisará acessar a página que preenche `'autorizacaoPainel'` antes de qualquer acesso ao painal.

Comment: Renan, na página principal do formulário eu coloquei um unset. assim:      <?php
      unset($_SESSION['usuarioNome'], $_SESSION['usuarioNivelAcesso']);
  ?>   para destruir a sessão atual, mas acho que não é assim... pq continua dando errado

Comment: Isso não destroi a sessão, mas apaga esses valore dela. No entanto, se o painel de admin ficar em outra página, você jamais terá certeza se essas variáveis de sessão tiveram seus valores apagados ou não.

Comment: Eu não entendi como fazer essa questão do token, entendi na teoria, mas nao sei como aplicar. Você tem algum material para me ajudar?

Comment: @PedroRibeiro adicionei código à resposta.

Comment: Continua dando para logar, copiando e colando o link